# How to keep each form state separate?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I have a list of **forms** that are populated by `ListView.builder.`

The user can fill out the form and save it. I want to save each form state separately using `Provider.`

I asked Bard AI, and that told me that you can do it with **Indexed Provider .** I could not understand that explanation.

Can anyone know this method or any other?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preferences.

Install using `flutter pub add shared_preferences`.
The examples and how to use is mentioned [here](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) in it's official website.